# Reload page without posting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a trouble. How can I refresh the page without any posting whenever I press F5 or Ctrl+F5?

I'm trying to do something like this, but it isn't working for me.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 116)
        window.location.reload("true");
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Like this.. `window.location.search += '&' + Math.random();`

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing the page will always repeat the previous request. The solution to this problem can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Basically, the form handler should do a "hard refresh" so that when the user does a browser refresh it does a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: Do you have some example how i can use this in javascript?

Comment: You can't do this in JavaScript. You have to issue the self-redirect from the server that gave you the page in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**BAD PATTERN WARNING: Please do not downvote.**

Just by curiosity, I've tried `window.top.location = window.top.location` on the console, and it seems to work. Maybe you can build upon it.

Comment: I'm not going to down vote but just to let you know this causes the client to post the previous request to the server resulting in a page reload and as mentioned a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
location.assign('same page url');
```